# Matlab `unstack`: Safe to assume ordering of new columns?

Tags: matlab, pivot

According to the [documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unstack.html), Matlab's `unstack` can take this table:

```
S=12×3 table
Storm    Town    Snowfall
_____    ____    ________

  3      'T1'        0   
  3      'T3'        3   
  1      'T1'        5   
  3      'T2'        5   
  1      'T2'        9   
  1      'T3'       10   
  4      'T2'       12   
  2      'T1'       13   
  4      'T3'       15   
  2      'T3'       16   
  4      'T1'       17   
  2      'T2'       21
```

...and convert it into:

```
U = unstack(S,'Snowfall','Town')

U=4×4 table
Storm    T1    T2    T3
_____    __    __    __

  3       0     5     3
  1       5     9    10
  4      17    12    15
  2      13    21    16
```

It seems reasonable to assume that the new columns are generated in alphabetic order.  To assume this would be fine if one is manually manipulating data, but is a deal breaker for automated data processing if one cannot be 100% assured of the ordering of the columns.  For example, if the `Town` column was actually a numerical index, then the new column names would be automatically generated so as to be legitimate variable names, and the ordering would be the key piece of information linking the new columns back to the values in the `Town` field.  If one extracts U{:,2:end} for manipulation, the data could be all wrong unless one could be 100% sure of whatever the scheme is for ordering the new columns.

I actually create a new column in place of `Town` containing a valid string, suffixed with the numerical index value.  These become the new column headings.  But the reality is, having to write extra code to assure that the columns appear in the right order is too much trouble.  It cancels out the benefit of unstack, and I ended up just creating loops to build up the new columns one by one.  Not efficient or elegant in terms of time and code.  I am trying to find a way to reliably exploit unstack in the future.

I have already submitted feedback describing the criticality of this bit of information, but I don't expect a response back any time soon.  Meanwhile, unstacking is such a useful function that I wonder whether anyone can weigh in about the advisability of assuming alphabetic ordering of the new columns?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, from what I understood in the code source of [`unstack.m`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unstack.html) (you can read it by typing `edit unstack`), the columns will be in alphabetical order following **Unicode alphabetical order** by using a function that converts the identifier to a unique index, *before* checking **if the identifier is valid**.

The [Unicode order](https://unicode-table.com) will mean in particular:

- that `T10` will be **before** `T9`.
- `t10`will be **after** `T10`.

According to `unstack`, the function that converts the identifier to a unique index `subs2inds` relies on a class `tabularDimension` which is said to be
(at R2018b) temporal:

```
%tabularDimension Internal abstract class to represent a tabular's dimension.

% This class is for internal use only and will change in a
% future release.  Do not use this class.
```

After sorting the identifiers, comes the validity checking with the function [`matlab.lang.makeValidName`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.lang.makevalidname.html) (using the default option `'Prefix','x'`) that will modify the identifier if is not valid (replacing illegal character by underscore by default).

> A valid MATLAB identifier is a character vector of alphanumerics (A–Z, a–z, 0–9) and underscores, such that the first character is a letter and the length of the character vector is less than or equal to `namelengthmax`.
>
> `makeValidName` deletes any whitespace characters before replacing any characters that are not alphanumerics or underscores. If a whitespace character is followed by a lowercase letter, `makeValidName` converts the letter to the corresponding uppercase character.

For example:

- `2A` will be change to `x2A`.
- `ça` will be change to `x_A`.

---

Particular case will be dealt with the help of the [`matlab.lang.makeuniquestrings`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.lang.makeuniquestrings.html) function.

For example, if you ask identifiers: `ç1`, `à1`, Matlab will still be able to distinguish them and rename them respectively `x_1_1`, `x_1`.

---

In your case, I will suggest to automatically generate columns with a constant starting letter, then the index with leading zeros resulting in a constant number of characters: `T0001`, `T0002`, ..., `T0100`, ..., `T9999`.

Comment: Bebs, thank you for reverse engineering the functionality. It means
that for the present, it can be relied upon to sort columns
alphanumerically, regardless of whether they are automatically
generated or created by myself.  The only question remaining is the
uncertainty in whether TMW will adhere to this undocumented behaviour
for the forseeable future.  I consider this to be a low risk, and would
be interested in knowing whether others share share this view.

Comment: Since I don't like the idea of relying on a black box generator, I
will convert numerical data (and other aribtrary data) to strings
using my own converter of data to identifier friendly encodings. I
need to control this so that the encodings are easily recognizable.  I
guess I shouldn't be surprised to see that Matlab has its own built-in
converter, as I've seen the need to create such a converter myself
just to wrestle data from outside into Matlab tables (the requirement
for identifier friendliness being for the column headings).

Comment: Do you mean get more info from TMW about formalizing the alphanumeric sorting of the new column headings, and a commitment to maintain this behaviour going forward?  That kind of certainty and stability would certainly make `unstack` more attractive to use. As I said, I've already supplied feedback to them (via the documentation page), but from the sounds of your comment, I assume that you have better access than the general public?

Comment: @user36800, I could confirm that in the deep parts of the code (`metaDim`), there is the mention : "This class is for internal use only and will change in a future release. Do not use this class."

Comment: Thanks, Bebs.  I think I will stick to my current clunkier code pattern of cycling through a series of joins so that I know the order in which I'm adding the columns.  Would you be able to add a caveat to your answer about the limited reliability of the order of added columns going forward?

Comment: Thanks!  That's a complete answer that keeps people aware of the hazards so that they can make the right judgement call.